# Custom Wordpress Theme, Bootstrap IE 8 not working properly

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

Hi everyone Im new to stackoverflow and this is my very first thread. I've been stuck on this issue for a very long time and I would like to get some help from people out there who smarter than me.

I began building a custom wordpress theme with the frameworks of bootstrap 3.0. I uploaded the site onto a web server and the website isn't working on IE 8 properly. The layout is all jumbled up (here is the website http://www.plummedia.com.au/).

If you look at my code I have Html5shiv.js , respond.js and css3mediaquieries.js in my header.

I tried going through these steps but it has been unsuccessful. http://davekiss.com/ie8-respond-js-and-wordpress/

Comment: your site is very very very very very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate your Document. You don't has closed all Tags.

`<div class="row-container">` for example has no `</div>` end. An invalid HTML - Thats **your** problem  and the problem of the browser - the browser cant fix that, goes to an compatiblity mode and faled by render the site.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.plummedia.com.au%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Its not the closing tag im using roughly the same code as i was before converting it to a wordpress theme

Comment: but your HTML is corrupted. The browser can't handle that - understand that?

Comment: Before I created a custom wordpress theme it was all roughly the same code and it worked before. Obviously it's something to do with the respond.js not reading my bootstrap.css can you please look more into it.